# 3D Rotation with camera

Tags: android, camera, rotation

I want to rotate imageview on the x and y axis with camera by this code and it works fine :

```
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromXDegrees = mFromXDegrees;
    float Xdegrees = fromXDegrees + ((mToXDegrees - fromXDegrees) * interpolatedTime);
    final float fromYDegrees = mFromYDegrees;
    float Ydegrees = fromYDegrees + ((mToYDegrees - fromYDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    camera.rotateX(Xdegrees);
    camera.rotateY(Ydegrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

but when I rotate a bitmap on the x and y axis the result is not good and is not same as imageview rotated by this code :

```
int width = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight();

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
int centerX = width / 2;
int centerY = height / 2;

Camera camera = new Camera();
camera.save();
camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
camera.rotateX(Xdegrees);
camera.rotateY(Ydegrees);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);
camera.restore();

matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, sourceBitmap.getConfig());
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, matrix, paint);
```

look at these results :

first image = main image

second image = imageview x : 20, y : 30

third image = bitmap x : 20, y : 30

[image: main image]

[image: imageview x = 20, y = 30]

[image: bitmap x = 20, y = 30]

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you point out which image goes with which code block?

Comment: @petey I edited the post, first image is normal image, second image is result of the first code block and third image is result of the second code block